# integrating R dataframes and performing operations based on column values

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, bioinformatics

I'm pretty new to R and so am having some difficulty with dataframes. I have two R dataframes that have different information and am wondering if there is a way to integrate one into the other in a meaningful way. I could not find a simple solution searching around, so I am hoping someone can help or give suggestions.

Specifically, I have an example dataframe as follows:

```
Scaffold  Start  Stop
E1        1      4
E1        5      12
E2        2      10
E3        1      10
E4        2      13
```

It represents start and stop sites for particular genes along a scaffold, with each row representing a specific gene.

Now I have a second output dataframe that reports FST stats for each individual site on a given scaffold:

```
Scaffold Site  FST
E1       1     0.1
E1       2     0.5
E1       3     0.6
E1       4     0.6
E1       5     0.8
E1       6     0.6
E1       7     0.4
E1       8     0.3
E2       2     0.2
E2       6     0.3
E2       7     0.5
E2       8     0.5
E2       9     0.6
E3       3     0.7
E3       5     0.7
E3       7     0.8
E4       2     0.8
E4       5     0.6
E4       6     0.5
E4       9     0.2
```

What I want to do is take the data from the second frame and integrate it into the first by calculating the average and max FST values for those intervals per row, to end up with something like this:

```
Scaffold  Start  Stop  Average.FST  Max.FST
E1        1      4     0.45         0.6
E1        5      12    0.53         0.8
E2        2      10    0.42         0.6
E3        1      10    0.73         0.8
E4        2      13    0.53         0.8
```

```
final <- data.frame("Scaffold" = c("E1","E1","E2","E3","E4"), 
                    "Start" = c(1,5,2,1,2), 
                    "Stop" =  c(4,12,10,10,13),
                    "Average FST" = c(0.45,0.53,0.42,0.73,0.53),
                    "Max FST" = c(0.6,0.8,0.6,0.8,0.8))
```

Thus, it's very similar to the first dataframe but integrates information from the second. Is there anyway to do this efficiently in R?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution using dplyr;

First I join to get all information related to each Scaffold from the second dataframe then using mutate I choose only those relevant (within the period) and then I get the average and maximum of the values.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <-
  data.frame(
    Scaffold = c("E1", "E1", "E2", "E3", "E4"),
    Start = c(1, 5, 2, 1, 2),
    Stop = c(4, 12, 10, 10, 13)
  )

df2 <-
  data.frame(
    Scaffold = c("E1", "E1", "E1", "E1", "E1", "E1", "E1", "E1", "E2", 
                 "E2", "E2", "E2", "E2", "E3", "E3", "E3", "E4", "E4", "E4", "E4"),
    Site = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 5, 7, 2, 5, 6, 9),
    FST = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 0.6, 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 
            0.6, 0.7, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8, 0.6, 0.5, 0.2)
  )

result <-
  df1 %>%
  inner_join(df2, by = c("Scaffold")) %>%
  mutate(FST = ifelse(Site >= Start & Site <= Stop, FST, NA)) %>%
  group_by(Scaffold, Start, Stop) %>%
  summarize(Average.FST = round(mean(FST, na.rm = TRUE), 2),
            Max.FST = max(FST, na.rm = TRUE))

result

# # A tibble: 5 x 5
# # Groups:   Scaffold, Start [5]
# Scaffold Start  Stop Average.FST Max.FST
# <fct>    <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl>
#   E1           1     4        0.45     0.6
#   E1           5    12        0.52     0.8
#   E2           2    10        0.42     0.6
#   E3           1    10        0.73     0.8
#   E4           2    13        0.52     0.8
```

Comment: Could also `filter` instead of assigning `NA` with `mutate`.  Like this: `df1 %>% left_join(df2, by = c("Scaffold" = "Scaffold")) %>% filter(Site >= Start & Site <= Stop)`

Answer (score 1):

We can use a join in `data.table` with `by` as `.EACHI`

```
library(data.table)
out <- setDT(df2)[df1, .(AverageFST = mean(FST), MaxFST = max(FST)),
      on = .(Scaffold, Site >= Start, Site <= Stop), by = .EACHI]
setnames(out, 2:3, c('Start', 'Stop'))[]
#  Scaffold Start Stop AverageFST MaxFST
#1:       E1     1    4  0.4500000    0.6
#2:       E1     5   12  0.5250000    0.8
#3:       E2     2   10  0.4200000    0.6
#4:       E3     1   10  0.7333333    0.8
#5:       E4     2   13  0.5250000    0.8
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R, we can first `merge` then `subset` and finally use `aggregate` to get required information.

```
aggregate(FST~Scaffold+Start+Stop, 
        subset(merge(df1, df2), Site >= Start & Site <= Stop), 
        function(x) c(average = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), max = max(x, na.rm = TRUE)))


#  Scaffold Start Stop FST.average FST.max
#1       E1     1    4        0.45    0.60
#2       E3     1   10        0.73    0.80
#3       E2     2   10        0.42    0.60
#4       E1     5   12        0.53    0.80
#5       E4     2   13        0.53    0.80
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Scaffold = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("E1", 
"E2", "E3", "E4"), class = "factor"), Start = c(1, 5, 2, 1, 2
), Stop = c(4, 12, 10, 10, 13)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

df2 <- structure(list(Scaffold = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("E1", 
"E2", "E3", "E4"), class = "factor"), Site = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
6, 7, 8, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 5, 7, 2, 5, 6, 9), FST = c(0.1, 0.5, 
0.6, 0.6, 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7, 
0.8, 0.8, 0.6, 0.5, 0.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```